# Installing Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) for Google Chrome creates .desktop files on my desktop

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, .desktop

I've installed several Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) using Google Chrome. It appears that Chrome creates a `.desktop` file in `~/Desktop` for each installed PWA. I imagine that some desktop environments will render these files on the desktop like a Windows shortcut icon, but Gnome doesn't seem to do so. Instead I have generic files with long hashed names cluttering up my desktop.

Can I safely delete these files to clean up my desktop? I know that Chrome installs another corresponding `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` that is slightly different than the one in `~/Desktop` in some cases, but I imagine that the `.desktop` file in `~/Desktop` is basically unnecessary.

I also imagine that the act of "installing" a PWA basically amounts to creating a `.desktop` file that launches Chrome in a certain mode, with a target website, and perhaps some cached credentials (i.e. no application is really being "installed" in the traditional sense). Therefore, I welcome any explanation giving clarity as to why Chrome would be creating these (additional) `.desktop` files in `~/Desktop`.

**Ubuntu Version:** 20.04.1

Comment: I have had better luck using Chromium (snap version) rather than Chrome. Chromium is almost the same software as Chrome. To install it, run `sudo snap install chromium`

Comment: You can also try Brave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can safely delete this file. As you said, there is another `.desktop` file that gets installed in `~/.local/share/applications/` .

If you want to fix the problem, make sure the GNOME Shell extension "Desktop Icons NG (DING)" is enabled. If it's not installed, install it by running:

```
 gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
```

Then search for the "Extensions" app and open it. Enable the "Desktop Icons NG (DING)" extension:

[image: Screenshot]

Now you should see the `.desktop` file on your desktop:

[image: Screenshot]

Right-click on it, and click "Allow launching". Now the `.desktop` icon will display properly:

[image: Screenshot]

I haven't found a way to get the web app to appear in GNOME Shell's search, or to pin the app to Ubuntu dash.

Comment: The command to mark a `.desktop` file as trusted is: `gio set example.desktop metadata::trusted true`